# Spark IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I'm trying to create a Spark Dataframe and I keep getting the following error , and this is completely running in my jupyter notebook but only happening in pycharm (flask API) I've been trying to rectify this issue for nearly 2 days and but none worked , my python version is 3.10.9 and spark version is 3.3.2  please let me know how to solve this

```
    params = {
        "spark.driver.memory": "16G",
        "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "2000M",
        "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "2000M",
        "spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl": "http://localhost:4041"
    }
    spark = sparknlp_jsl.start(license_keys['SECRET'], params=params)
    print("Spark NLP Version :")
    spark_ins = spark
    print("Spark NLP Version :", sparknlp.version())
    print("Spark NLP_JSL Version :", sparknlp_jsl.version())
    # spark_pipeline(spark,pipeline_all=clinical_profiling_pipeline_instance)


    sample_text = [
        "The patient is a 60-years-old native american woman, diagnosed with liver cancer at age 58. She is a nonsmoker and has no other medical history.",
        "The patient is a 69 y.o. man with prostatic cancer. He was diagnosed at age 65, and he quit smoking at that time.",
        "She has no family history of cancer, and none in her family is a smoker."]

    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
    df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_text, StringType()).toDF('text')
```

Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\serializers.py", line 437, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 72, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 540, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 630, in reducer_override
    return self._function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 503, in _function_reduce
    return self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 484, in _dynamic_function_reduce
    state = _function_getstate(func)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 156, in _function_getstate
    f_globals_ref = _extract_code_globals(func.__code__)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 236, in _extract_code_globals
    out_names = {names[oparg] for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 236, in <setcomp>
    out_names = {names[oparg] for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
                 ~~~~~^^^^^^^
```

I tried different python versions by changing conda environments and tried updating cloudpickle and also converting pandas dataframe to spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `list` approach you need this:

```
sample_text = [
    ("The patient is a 60-years-old native american woman, diagnosed with liver cancer at age 58. She is a nonsmoker and has no other medical history."),
    ("The patient is a 69 y.o. man with prostatic cancer. He was diagnosed at age 65, and he quit smoking at that time."),
    ("She has no family history of cancer, and none in her family is a smoker.")]
```

No need for `from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType` twice, slight copy, paste error presumably.

Please accept answer as per protocol.

Comment: externally sorry for the late reply , I managed to fix the issue by changing to following code , 
    df = spark_instance.createDataFrame([sample_text]).toDF("text")
    med_result = pipe_line_medicine.transform(df)
I accepted your answer but I didn't tested in by myself , however the code I had worked on jupyter and it failed only on pycharm